# Querying polymorphic associations causing validity error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a polymorphic association in my app to track orders in my app.  I'd like to be able to query `Meal`, a model that is `:orderable` but for some reason after adding the association, calls to `:valid?` throw an error.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :orderables, through: :order_items, source: :orderable, source_type: 'Meal'
end

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :meal, -> { where( order_items: { orderable_type: 'Meal' } ).includes(:meal) }, foreign_key: 'orderable_id'

  belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :order_present
  validate :item_present

  scope :are_veggies, -> { includes( :meal ).where( :meals => { type_of: 'veggie' }) }
  scope :are_meals, -> { includes( :meal ).where.not( :meals => { type_of: 'veggie' }) }

    private

  def item_present
    if orderable.present? and !orderable.active
      errors.add(:orderable, "Selected item is not available.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end
end

class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    has_many :tags, as: :taggable
    has_many :order_items, as: :orderable

    validates_presence_of :name, :type_of

    default_scope { where(active: true) }
end
```

All the queries work properly, I can call `Order.find(x).meals`.  I can call `Order.find(x).order_items.are_meals`.

But when I attempt to call `OrderItem.find(x).valid?` I see an error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Meal' to association named 'meal'; perhaps you misspelled it?`.  Any idea what is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I was including the wrong model:

```
# This
belongs_to :meal, -> { where( order_items: { orderable_type: 'Meal' } ).includes(:meal) }, foreign_key: 'orderable_id'

# Should have been
belongs_to :meal, -> { where( order_items: { orderable_type: 'Meal' } ).includes(:order_items) }, foreign_key: 'orderable_id'
```